# Deleting a member array of pointers, then reallocating it

Tags: c++

I'm creating a stack class as an exercise trying to learn some c++ concepts (initializer lists, memory management and templates here). I've run into something that I can't get my head around.

In function void Stack::push(const T& item), if I uncomment the delete [] data; line, my code runs well when the template argument is for example int or char. But with std::string, I get weird memory errors.

My thinking here is that I need a bigger array -> arrays can't be resized -> I create a new one -> I deallocate the memory I needed for the one that's soon to be not needed -> I make the existing pointer point to a new memory address where I create the bigger array.

Now, when I comment the delete line, the code runs well even with std::string, but I can't see why I can't do the delete operation safely with all types.

Any insights will be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

template<class T>
class Stack
{
    T* data;
    int sz;

public:
    //Stack(){sz=0;}
    Stack(const std::initializer_list<T>&);
    ~Stack();

    void push(const T&);
    T& pop();

    void show() const;
};

template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack(const std::initializer_list<T> &list)
{
    sz=0;
    data = new T[list.size()];

    for (auto i : list) {
        data[sz] = i;
        ++sz;
    }
    std::cout<< "Created with sz:  "<< sz<<std::endl;
}

template<class T>
Stack<T>::~Stack()
{
    delete [] data;
}

template<class T> 
void Stack<T>::push(const T& item) {
    std::cout<<"push "<<item<<std::endl;
    T* arr = new T[sz];
    memcpy(arr, data, sz*sizeof(T));
    //delete [] data;
    data = new T[sz + 1];
    memcpy(data, arr, sz*sizeof(T));
    ++sz;
    data[sz - 1] = item;
    std::cout<<"new size: "<<sz<<", bytes: "<<sz*sizeof(T)<<std::endl;
}

template<class T>
T& Stack<T>::pop()
{
    if(sz > 0) {
        std::cout<<"pop "<<data[sz-1]<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"new size: "<<sz-1<<std::endl;
        return data[--sz];
    }
    else
        return data[0];
}

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::show() const
{
    for (int i=0; i<sz; i++) {
        std::cout<<data[i]<<" ";
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    Stack<int> s = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
    s.show();
    s.push(12);
    s.push(13);
    s.push(14);
    s.pop();
    s.pop();
    s.push(15);
    s.push(16);
    s.show();
    Stack<std::string> d = {"one","two","three"};
    d.show();
    d.pop();
    d.push("four");
    d.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Calling `delete[]` calls the destructor of the objects in the array, but you don't want them to be destroyed, as you are just moving them. In the end, the destructor gets called twice, which leads to errors.

Comment: I was under a false impression of what delete [] actually does. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `memcpy` to copy objects, that will copy the bits alright, but for some object a bit-wise copy is not correct as the copy constructor (or copy assignment operator) Will not be used.

A good and simple example is if you have a stack of `std::string` objects. When you do a bit-wise copy (with `memcpy`) the contents of the `std::string` *objects* are copied, but that basically is just a pointer and a size. When you do a bit-wise copy then you will have two `std::string` objects referencing the same memory. Destroying one of those object will lead to the other having a stray pointer to some memory (that used to contain the string) that no longer is owned by your program.

To solve this use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) instead to copy the objects, it will do the right thing.

---

Unrelated to your problem, but your `push` function does a copy that it doesn't need:

```
T* arr = new T[sz];
memcpy(arr, data, sz*sizeof(T));
```

This is simply not needed, instead do something like

```
T* oldData = data;
data = new T[sz + 1];

// Copy from old array to new
std::copy(oldData, oldData + sz, data);

delete[] oldData;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the example, it really helped a lot.

Comment: For clarification for future readers, there was a slight mistake in the usage of std::copy above. Correct format is std::copy(oldData, oldData+sz, data);, because parameters are iterators from source start, source end, destination start. With that fixed, using std::copy solved my issue.